# Centering content of field in centre of field

Tags: blackberry

[image]I made one horizontalfieldmaanger which will take full width and 10% height of screen. Now I want to add 3 fields to this manager respectively. First will be BitmapField(10% width of screen), second will be LabelField(80% width of screen), third will be BitmapField(10% width of screen).

Its all done thing that is remaining is centering contents of these fields to centre within field itself.

Here is code:-

```
public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen
{
public MyScreen()
{   
    final int disWidth = Display.getWidth();
    final int disHeight = Display.getHeight();
    final int heightHFM = (disHeight*10)/100;

    HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager(){
        protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.sublayout(maxWidth, maxHeight);
            this.setExtent(disWidth,heightHFM);

    }
    };
    hfm.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.GRAY));

    BitmapField bmp_leftArrow = new BitmapField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("arrow_left.png")){
        protected void layout(int width, int height) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.layout(width, height);
            this.setExtent((disWidth*10)/100, height);
        }
    };
    bmp_leftArrow.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.BLUE));

    LabelField lbl_tit = new LabelField("Current Date"){
        protected void layout(int width, int height) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.layout(width, height);
            this.setExtent((disWidth*80)/100, height);
        }
    };
    lbl_tit.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.RED));
    BitmapField bmp_rightArrow = new BitmapField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("arrow_left.png")){
        protected void layout(int width, int height) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.layout(width, height);
            this.setExtent((disWidth*10)/100, height);
        }
    };
    bmp_rightArrow.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.GREEN));
    hfm.add(bmp_leftArrow);
    hfm.add(lbl_tit);
    hfm.add(bmp_rightArrow);
    add(hfm);

}
}
```

**Need to achieve same output when we use gravity of any view in android**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For custom positioning and alignment of the child fields, A dedicated FieldManger with specified layout and field positioning is useful. You can try the following `CustomHorizontalFieldManager` which extends `Manager`.

*Generated Output*

[image]

*Using the Manager*

```java
public class MyScreen extends MainScreen
{
    public MyScreen()
    {        
        CustomHorizontalFieldManager chfm = new CustomHorizontalFieldManager();
        Background bg = BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.BROWN);
        chfm.setBackground(bg);

        BitmapField bmf0 = new BitmapField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("img0.png"));
        BitmapField bmf1 = new BitmapField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("img1.png"));

        CutomLabelField lblf = new CutomLabelField("Current Date");

        bg = BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.GREEN);
        lblf.setBackground(bg);

        bg = BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.GREEN);
        bmf0.setBackground(bg);

        bg = BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.GREEN);
        bmf1.setBackground(bg);

        chfm.add(bmf0);
        chfm.add(lblf);
        chfm.add(bmf1);

        add(chfm);
    }
}
```

*Implementation of the Manager*

```java
class CustomHorizontalFieldManager extends Manager {

    public CustomHorizontalFieldManager() {
        super(0);
    }

    private int width0, width1, width2;
    private Field f0, f1, f2;
    int x0, x1, x2, y0, y1, y2;

    protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
        if (getFieldCount() == 3) {
            // calculate total width, total height
            width = Display.getWidth();
            height = getPercentage(Display.getHeight(), 10);

            // calculate field's width
            width0 = getPercentage(width, 10);
            width1 = getPercentage(width, 80);
            width2 = getPercentage(width, 10);

            f0 = getField(0);
            f1 = getField(1);
            f2 = getField(2);

            // layout all the child
            layoutChild(f0, width0, height);
            layoutChild(f1, width1, height);
            layoutChild(f2, width2, height);

            // Specify position of the child.           
            // Alignment of the fields can be adjusted here.
            // Following lines will align them
            // on center, both vertically and horizontally.
            x0 = (width0 - f0.getWidth()) / 2;
            x1 = width0 + (width1 - f1.getWidth()) / 2;
            x2 = width0 + width1 + (width2 - f2.getWidth()) / 2;

            y0 = (height - f0.getHeight()) / 2;
            y1 = (height - f1.getHeight()) / 2;
            y2 = (height - f2.getHeight()) / 2;

            setPositionChild(f0, x0, y0);
            setPositionChild(f1, x1, y1);
            setPositionChild(f2, x2, y2);

            setExtent(width, height);
        } else {
            // The manager contains some
            // invalid number of fields.

            // Make manager invisible.
            setExtent(0, 0);
        }
    }   

    int getPercentage(int value, int percent) {
        return (value * percent) / 100;
    }
}
```

*Draft implementation of CustomLabelField*

```java
class CutomLabelField extends Field {
    private String text;

    public CutomLabelField(String text) {
        this.text = (text == null) ? "" : text;
    }

    int xText;
    int yText;  
    int availableWidth;

    protected void layout(int width, int height) {      
        // positioning text.
        int textWidth = getFont().getAdvance(text);
        availableWidth = width - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
        if (availableWidth < textWidth) {
            xText = getPaddingLeft();
        } else {
            xText = getPaddingLeft() + (availableWidth - textWidth) / 2;
        }
        yText = (height - getFont().getHeight()) / 2;

        // using all width and height
        setExtent(width, height);
    }

    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        // set text color
        graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        graphics.drawText(text, xText, yText, DrawStyle.ELLIPSIS, availableWidth);
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = (text == null) ? "" : text;
        updateLayout();
    }

    public String getText() {
        return this.text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice this worked I also understand proper use of layoutChild and setPositionChild thank you for this clean example, though my requirement was for centering content of field to centre in this example whole field is get centered(You can check this by giving background to fields which you are adding to manager.) Can we do this thing?

Comment: I have added some background on those fields, and also add the updated output on answer. If I understand your question well, then I think it is okay. But if not, then you can customized these fields, and override their paint and layout methods to achieve what you want. The customization procedure will be the same as `CustomHorizontalFeidlManager`, but the paint method also needs to be implemented.

Comment: Hello, see this background is positioning only to text (background to "current text" only) instead it should cover whole height(10% of screen here) and width(80% that what we provided to this field). SO that green color will cover whole space and "Current text" will be centered to this color both vertically and horizontally.You can check picture of dontruner that he provided butin this text is centered horizontally only(Note here Red color covers whole height and width)

Comment: Check updated code, and output. I have added an implementation of `CustomLabelField` which use all available width and height for itself. And the default text alignment for it is horizontal and vertical center. Using that concept you can customize other types of Field, and edit their default alignment.

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked I also understand basic methods of blackberry.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding your `LabelField` (variable `lbl_tit`) directly to your `HorizontalFieldManager` add it to a `VerticalFieldManager` first. Then add the `VerticalFieldManager` to your `HorizontalFieldManager`.

When you create your `LabelField` set the `Field.FIELD_HCENTER` style bit to center align it within the `VerticalFieldManager`.

Here's my code:

```
public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen
{
    public MyScreen()
    {   
        final int disWidth = Display.getWidth();
        final int disHeight = Display.getHeight();
        final int heightHFM = (disHeight*10)/100;

        HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager(){
            protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
                super.sublayout(maxWidth, maxHeight);
                this.setExtent(disWidth,heightHFM);

            }
        };
        hfm.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.GRAY));

        BitmapField bmp_leftArrow = new BitmapField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("arrow_left.png")){
            protected void layout(int width, int height) {
                super.layout(width, height);
                this.setExtent((disWidth*10)/100, height);
            }
        };
        bmp_leftArrow.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.BLUE));

        VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH){

            protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
                super.sublayout((disWidth*80)/100, height);
                this.setExtent((disWidth*80)/100, height);                   
            }        
        };

        vfm.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.RED));

        LabelField lbl_tit = new LabelField("Current Date", Field.FIELD_HCENTER);
        vfm.add(lbl_tit);

        BitmapField bmp_rightArrow = new BitmapField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("arrow_left.png")){
            protected void layout(int width, int height) {
                super.layout(width, height);
                this.setExtent((disWidth*10)/100, height);
            }
        };
        bmp_rightArrow.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.GREEN));
        hfm.add(bmp_leftArrow);
        hfm.add(vfm);
        hfm.add(bmp_rightArrow);
        add(hfm);

    }
}
```

Remove the overridden `layout` method from your LabelField, you don't need it any more. It should look like this:

[image: Simulator screenshot]

Comment: I tried as you said but same result :-

VerticalFieldManager verticalFieldManager = new VerticalFieldManager();
     LabelField lbl_tit = new LabelField("Current Date",Field.FIELD_HCENTER){
      protected void layout(int width, int height) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.layout(width, height);
       this.setExtent((disWidth*80)/100, height);
      }
     };
     lbl_tit.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.RED));
     verticalFieldManager.add(lbl_tit);
..

hfm.add(bmp_leftArrow);
     hfm.add(verticalFieldManager);
     hfm.add(bmp_rightArrow);

Comment: I wonder how you achieved this, I am doing same as you told me but its not working, in your example its centering vertically not horizontally i want to show this text "Current Date" in vertically as well as horizontally..

Comment: VerticalFieldManager verticalFieldManager = new VerticalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH){
      protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
       
       super.sublayout((disWidth*80)/100, maxHeight);
       this.setExtent((disWidth*80)/100, maxHeight);
      }
     };
     LabelField lbl_tit = new LabelField("Current Date",FIELD_HCENTER);

hfm.add(verticalFieldManager);

Comment: When i give USE_ALL_WIDTH to VerticalFieldManager, instead taking 80% it takes whole screen.

Comment: @R.j., You can use a custom field layout manager, which can take the responsibility of the position and alignment of the child fields.